# How to pass method name at runtime to component generated by DynamicComponent in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to render dynamic content in Blazor Wasm using [DynamicComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0) from .Net 6. The component to render is defined in a JSON file with the following structure.

```
{
   "type":"MyButton",
   "parameters": {
       "Label":"My Buttom",
       "OnClicked": "DoAction"
   } 
}
```

DynamicComponent allows us to pass parameters to the rendered Component using Dictionary<string, object> like the code below where we can define component.parameters as Dictionary<string,object>

```
<DynamicComponent Type=@component.type Parameters=@component.parameters />
```

In my razor file, I have defined the "DoAction()" method. I want the this method to be called when the MyButton component is clicked. But how can we pass this DoAction() method as EventCallBack to the rendered Component?

MyButton.razor component:

```cs
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="HandledClicked">@LabelText</button>

@code{
  [Parameter]
  public string LabelText {get; set;}

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback OnClicked { get; set; }

  private void HandleClicked()
  {
    OnClicked.InvokeAsync();
  }
}
```

DynamicPage.razor: (Update #1)

```cs
@page "/DynamicPage"

@foreach (var component in components)
{
  <DynamicComponent Type="component.Type" Parameters="component.Parameters" />
}

@code{
  List<JsonComponent> components = new();

  protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     var jsonComponentList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<JsonComponent>>("/data.json");  

     foreach (var item in jsonComponentList)
     {
        JsonComponent componentItem = new();
        componentItem.Type = Type.GetType($"{nameSpaceComponents}{item.Type}");
        componentItem.Parameters = new();

        // below code to populate the component parameters as Dictionary<string, object>.
        // the problem here is how to pass "DoAction()" method which is defined in the 
        // Json file to the rendered component by adding it to the paramater Dictionary<string, object>?

       foreach (var kvp in item.Parameters)
       {
         var jsonElement = ((JsonElement)kvp.Value).GetString();
         componentItem.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, jsonElement);  
       }
     }
  }  

  public void DoAction()
  {
     //.. codes to perform some custom logic here when Button component is clicked.
  }

}
```

JsonComponent.cs Class:

```cs
public class JsonComponent
{
  public JsonComponent()
  {
  }

  public Type Type { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to add a @ref, define a variable referencing your component and call the method you want.

Comment: The method name is defined in JSON file and not known at design time in the rendered Button component. During runtime, the JSON content is read and then Button component is generated dynamically. Hence, I don't think we can fixed at design time using @ref variable to call the intended method.

Comment: In C# (documentation online) you can instantiate a class by name and also you can call a method by name.

Comment: I tried to use Reflection to get the Method by name in the EventCallBackFactory class but it gives compilation error in VS. `var callback = EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, this.GetType().GetMethod("DoAction"));`
`componentItem.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, callback);`

Comment: I am not seeing your MyButton.razor component is being used in the DynamicPage.  Can you please show where you intended to insert that component?

Comment: @JasonD , I have updated the DynamicPage.razor code to make it clearer in the Question (Update #1). MyButton component is defined in Json file and get render dynamically using `<DynamicComponent Type="component.Type" Parameters="component.Parameters" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass the method or function at runtime to the dynamically generated Component via the Dictionary<string, object> Parameters, we need to create an EventCallBack by using `EventCallback.Factory.Create()` method.

I use the `foreach` loop to get the list of parameters defined in the Json file that we need to add into the Dictionary<string, object> Parameters.

Then I have an `if` condition to check whether the parameter to be passed to the Component is an Event. Here I predefined all Event Key name should prefix with 'On' e.g. 'OnClicked'. If the parameter is an Event then we create an EventCallback

```cs
    callback = EventCallBack.Factory.Create<string>(this, (Action<string>) this.GetType().GetMethod(kvp.Value.ToString()).CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>), this));
    componentItem.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, callback);
```

Below is the codes for the DynamicPage.razor:

```cs
@page "/DynamicPage"

@foreach (var component in components)
{
  <DynamicComponent Type="component.Type" Parameters="component.Parameters" />
}

@code{
  List<JsonComponent> components = new();
  EventCallBack<string> callback;  // Declare a EventCallBack variable use to pass to the generated Component

  protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     var jsonComponentList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<JsonComponent>>("/data.json");  
   
     foreach (var item in jsonComponentList)
     {
       JsonComponent componentItem = new();
       componentItem.Type = Type.GetType($"{nameSpaceComponents}{item.Type}");
       componentItem.Parameters = new();
        
       foreach (var kvp in item.Parameters)
       {
         var jsonElement = ((JsonElement)kvp.Value).GetString();
         if (kvp.Key.ToString().StartsWith("On"))
         {
           callback = EventCallBack.Factory.Create<string>(this, (Action<string>) this.GetType().GetMethod(kvp.Value.ToString()).CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>), this));
           componentItem.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, callback);
         }
         else
         {
           componentItem.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, jsonElement);  
         }
       }
       components.Add(componentItem);
     }
  }
}
```